# Distribution of minimum of independent normal variables

Tags: statistics, order-statistics

Suppose $X_t\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2t)$, $X_t$ are independent. Is the distribution of $$\min_{0\leq t\leq T}X_t$$known? In other words can this probability be found $$P(\min_{0\leq t\leq T}X_t\leq a)?$$ I have seen some results about the $\min(X,Y)$ but this is not exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: You need to say something about the _joint_ distribution of the random variables $X_t$.

Comment: If one considers infinitely many independent random variables, the minimum is actually an infimum and equals $-\infty$ almost surely. Sure this is your question?

Comment: Why are you leaving this question in disarray?

Comment: No that was not my question. I realised that I can use a different way and avoid it

Answer (score 2):

$$P(\min_{0\leq t\leq T}X_t\leq a) =1 - P(all X_t >a)$$

Since $X_t$ are all independent, then this equals:

$$1 - P(X_1>a)*P(X_2 >a)*...*P(X_T>a)$$

You can use that to find the pdf.

Comment: Except that there are uncountably many terms on the right side....

Comment: Oh, I took the uppercase T in the question to be finite (updated my answer to reflect that). If we want infinite t's that certainly changes things.